# The "flag or disagree..." should shrink an expanded answer/question

Tags: bug, 10k-tools

When using the moderator tools and reviewing flags, one can *enlarge* the flagged question/answer by hitting the little arrow next to the question title, as shown on the privileges page.

Now, when I hit the "**close question...**"-button and close the question, after closing it the enlarged question is automatically shrunk to just one line, containing only it's title:

[image]

Now, when using the "**flag or disagree...**"-button and flagging the question/answer, that does not happen. Is this supposed to be? Because to me, it feels like an error.